# Is the enteric nervous system found only in vertebrates?

Tags: neuroscience, anatomy

The enteric nervous system is distinguished by being autonomous from the central nervous system and capable of independent action, such as the peristaltic reflex. For this reason the the intestines can be removed from the body of a vertebrate creature and they will still function.

Is this type of nervous system unique to vertebrates, or is it found in invertebrates and insects as well?

Comment: A Google search of "enteric nervous systems of invertebrates" yields rich results, such as [How To Innervate A Simple Gut: Familiar Themes And Unique Aspects In The Formation Of The Insect Enteric Nervous System](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3097047/). Searching before posting is always a good practice.